# Php TCPDF an image for each language u choose in website

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to generate an PDF with all information of a products, with description, characteristics, standards, technologies as a data sheet pdf generator.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/si/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
class OCPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Header() {
        
                if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
                    $server = HTTP_SERVER;
                } else {
                    $server = HTTPS_SERVER;
                }  
              
                //$language = $this->config->get('config_language'); ERROR IT WAS A TEST BUT DOEST WORK
                $language = 'pt-pt'; // Replace with the actual language code
                if (isset($this->session->data['language'])) {
                    $language = $this->session->data['language'];
                }

                // Set the image file based on the language
                $logo_file = 'image/catalog/pdftemplate/header.png';
                if ($language == 'en-gb') {
                    $logo_file = $server . 'image/catalog/pdftemplate/header-en.png';
                } elseif ($language == 'es') {
                    $logo_file = $server . 'image/catalog/pdftemplate/header-es.png';
                } elseif ($language == 'pt-pt') {
                    $logo_file = $server . 'image/catalog/pdftemplate/header-pt.png';
                }

                $header_details_address = $this->header_details_address;
                 $header_details_email = $this->header_details_email;
             echo $language;  
$header_html = <<<EOD

<img src ="$logo_file" height="190px">
<br/><br/><br/><br/>

EOD;

                    // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
                    $this->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $header_html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
                }

                // Page footer
                public function Footer() {
                    // Position at 15 mm from bottom
                    $this->SetY(-25);
                    // Set font
                    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
                    // Page number
                    
                    if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
                        $server = HTTP_SERVER;
                    } else {
                        $server = HTTPS_SERVER;
                    }  
                    
                    $mlogo_file =  $server.'image/catalog/pdftemplate/footer.png' ;
                    
                    $footer_logo_html = '<div style="width:100% !important;height:190px;"><img width:"100%;" src="' . $footer_image_file . '" /></div>';
                    $this->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, $this->Image($mlogo_file, '0', $this->GetY()+2, '210', 24, '', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
                }
                
                public function setImageFile($logo_file)
                {
                    $this->logo_file = $logo_file ;
                }
                
                public function setStoreheader_details($header_details_address ,$header_details_email)
                {
                    $this->header_details_address=$header_details_address;
                    $this->header_details_email = $header_details_email;
                }
            }

This is my tring code:
```

//$language = $this->config->get('config_language'); ERROR IT WAS A TEST BUT DOEST WORK
$language = 'pt-pt'; // Replace with the actual language code
if (isset($this->session->data['language'])) {
$language = $this->session->data['language'];
}

```
            // Set the image file based on the language
            $logo_file = 'image/catalog/pdftemplate/header.png';
            if ($language == 'en-gb') {
                $logo_file = $server . 'image/catalog/pdftemplate/header-en.png';
            } elseif ($language == 'es') {
                $logo_file = $server . 'image/catalog/pdftemplate/header-es.png';
            } elseif ($language == 'pt-pt') {
                $logo_file = $server . 'image/catalog/pdftemplate/header-pt.png';
            }
```

```
But I can't set language for the images, I did it for the text but when I try to do it for images, I get multiple errors.

Can someone help me figure it out? I need to have different headers and footers for each language I've selected in website!

With text I was capable to change text based on the language with this:
```

class ControllerExtensionModulesiproductpdf extends Controller {
private $modulePath;
public function __construct($registry) {

```
            parent::__construct($registry);
            $this->config->load('si/siproductpdf');
            $this->modulePath = $this->config->get('siproductpdf_path');

        }

        public function index($settings){
            
            ///
            if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                $product_id = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
            } else {
                $product_id = 0;
            }
            
            $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/siproductpdf.css');
            //$data['moduleData'] = $settings['siproductpdf'];
            $data['status'] = (isset($settings['status'])) ? $settings['status'] : false;
            $data['language_id'] = $this->config->get('config_language_id'); //HERE 
            $data['pdffile'] = HTTPS_SERVER . 'index.php?route=extension/module/siproductpdf/downloadproductpdf&product_id='.$product_id;
            return $this->load->view($this->modulePath, $data);
        }
```

```
Output error when I activate
```

$language = $this->config->get('config_language');
//$language = ''; // Replace with the actual language code

```
*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/coelhost/cls.pt/catalog/controller/extension/module/siproductpdf.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/coelhost/cls.pt/system/config/si/tcpdf/tcpdf.php(3541): OCPDF->Header() #1 /home/coelhost/cls.pt/system/config/si/tcpdf/tcpdf.php(3208): TCPDF->setHeader() #2 /home/coelhost/cls.pt/system/config/si/tcpdf/tcpdf.php(3120): TCPDF->startPage('', '', false) #3 /home/coelhost/cls.pt/catalog/controller/extension/module/siproductpdf.php(273): TCPDF->AddPage() #4 /home/coelhost/cls.pt/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-storage_modification_system_engine_action.php(79): ControllerExtensionModulesiproductpdf->downloadproductpdf() #5 /home/coelhost/cls.pt/catalog/controller/startup/router.php(25): Action->execute(Object(Registry)) #6 /home/coelhost/cls.pt/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-storage_modification_system_engine_action.php(79): ControllerStartupRouter->index() #7 /home/coelhost/cls.pt/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-storage_modification_system_engine_router.php(130): Action->execute(Object(Registry)) in /home/coelhost/cls.pt/catalog/controller/extension/module/siproductpdf.php on line 17*
```

Comment: _"but when i try to do it for images i have multiple errors"_ - _what_ errors? If you are getting any actual error _messages_, then please quote them verbatim.

Comment: `$logo_file = 'image/catalog/pdftemplate/header.png';` - why is _this_ a relative path, but then within your if conditions, you are prefixing the relative paths you are using in there, with `$server`? And what does this variable actually contain, is that at least something ending with a slash? Otherwise, directly concatenating `image/...` to it can hardly make any sense to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe I edit and added the output error when i activate the GET language_code

Comment: Those errors are coming from deep within the library itself. Most likely reason is probably that you specified an invalid path for the images you are trying to use.